# "transcend" in a negative context

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Can transcend be used to imply a negative condition? For example, "an unappointed ruling elite that transcends both of the member groups." The implication would be that the elite group is comprised of members from the two different groups but is not beholden to the groups. Not in the sense of say, statesmanship, but in the sense of manipulation. Is there a better word than transcend to use to connote that meaning?

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions. To address the second one: how about “an unappointed ruling elite that ***derives from*** [or ***is derived from***] both of the member groups”?

Comment: Transcend does not imply that the transcendent being is a member of the lower group. More that it has moved on above and beyond the group.

Comment: One can say that (for example) a political policy transcends sanity. This is not a compliment.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Scott. So, using your words, you could describe it as 'a ruling elite deriving from, yet unbeholden to, both of the member groups'.
'Unanswerable to' would also substitute.

Answer (score 1):

I think either `outstrip` or `overshadow` might work if you are wanting to keep this sentence structure, though as Oldcat said you may want to add words in to specify that the elite derives from either group. You might consider the word "constituent" (being a part of the whole, i.e. each group is a constituent of the ruling elite, though this may be confusing in a political sense since constituent can also mean a voting member).

I think overshadows works particularly well for your use, especially since it keeps the tense you want.

> An unappointed ruling elite that **overshadows** both of the member
> groups.
>
> An unappointed ruling elite that **overshadows** both of its **constituent**
> groups.

Or:

> An unappointed ruling elite that **outstripped** both of the member
> groups.

You could also say "outsrips" but that seems to me a strange use of tense for that word in this context.

Otherwise an entire rephrasing like thecrease suggested might work well.